# Artifact appear on desktop wallpaper and icons

Tags: 20.04

The wallpaper picture on my PC often appear artifacts, randomly, but mostly after a crash and reboot (it only has 12GB RAM so it often gets laggy and hang). Screenshot:
[image]

Sometimes the artifacts even appear on app icons, or the icons completely gone (but still clickable, just lost the image):
[image]
[image]
I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS